# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null when creating new wallet

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I'm using the code given on the docs to create a new wallet, and it says that I am getting a: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null error.

My code looks like:

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

// blank intentionally, but completed actually
var client = new Client({
    'apiKey': '',
    'apiSecret': '',
});

client.createAccount({'name': 'New Wallet'}, function(err, acct) {
    console.log(acct.name + ': ' + acct.balance.amount + ' ' + acct.balance.currency);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post more of your code by any chance? It should be working if everything else is as the docs suggest. Maybe you've made a mistake somewhere else? Thanks. You can also try `if (err) throw err;` inside the function to see if an error has occurred.

Comment: Did you check your return value `acct`? The error message is quite obvious: `acct` is equal to `null`. When you have a callback, start by checking the return value for `err`. Check the following for more details: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-best-practices/.

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi updated code

Comment: Maybe add 'version to the client definition JSON as per https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/bitcoin-wallet? Not sure if this will make a difference, but it may change the requested URL.

Comment: I've tried that already, at the beginning. Doesn't fix anything :/

Comment: Interesting... Maybe see https://github.com/bchavez/Coinbase/issues/21. It suggests to double check that your system time is correct as Coinbase is apparently time-sensitive.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, no problem.

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi I found that my acct is null. Why is this? Shouldn't a default account be made for me at the start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172487/discussion-between-olivier-gabison-and-pal-kerecsenyi).

Answer (score 1):

`acct` is null, maybe because `createAccount` gives you an error. Try to

```
if(err){
 //handle err
 console.log(err)
}
```

This should give more information about what's going on

Comment: when I do this, I get an AuthenticationError: invalid signature error.

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with your `client` object, regarding the authentication. Try to review the coinbase documentation and I recommend to update the question providing more details about how you set the client and about the error `AuthenticationError` that you get when running the code

Comment: Actually, my acct is null. How do I make it 'unnull'?